Apache Beam -> BigQuery: Storage Write API doesn't respect Primary Key
I have a BigQuery table created using the following DDL:
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
(
  id STRING,
  source STRING,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
);

As you can see, id is set as the table Primary Key. My Beam pipeline is then defined as follows:
def process_message(message):  
    import apache_beam as beam
    import struct
    data = json.loads(message.decode("utf-8"))
    if data == {}:
        print(f"Running DELETE operation on row {this_message['Key']}")
        data['_CHANGE_TYPE'] = 'DELETE'
    else:   
        print(f"Running UPSERT operation on row {this_message['Key']}")
        data['_CHANGE_TYPE'] = 'UPSERT'
    data['_CHANGE_SEQUENCE_NUMBER'] = str(struct.pack('d', int(round(float(this_message['Value']['updated'])))).hex())
    return [data]


with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions([
    f"--project={project_id}",
    "--region=europe-west2",
    "--runner=DataflowRunner",
    "--streaming",
    "--temp_location=gs://tmp/cdc",
    "--staging_location=gs://tmp/cdc",
])) as pipeline:
  data = pipeline | 'ReadFromPubSub' >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=f'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{bq_table_name}')

  data | 'ProcessMessages' >> beam.ParDo(process_message) | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(
    f'{project_id}:{bq_dataset}.{bq_table_name}',
    schema=schema,
    method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API,
    triggering_frequency=5
  )

However, when I query my table in BigQuery after consuming a handful of records, I have hundreds of duplicates of the id field.
How do I get my pipeline to respect the primary key and perform an UPSERT operation, as it should do?

It looks like you're trying to achieve CDC writes and you would need to set: use_cdc_writes to true and you would need to provide row_mutation_info on a per record basis.
For more info, please refer to https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.61.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html
